# Convert Model.Objects.all() to JSON in python using django

Tags: python, json, django

I have a list of objects of the same model type. I want to iterate over this list and create a JSON to send back. I tried some things like 2-dim arrays, google,... but can't find something like this? Though I think it can't be difficult.

my code now is:

```
def get_cashflows(request):

        response_data = {}
        cashflow_set = Cashflow.objects.all();
        i = 0;
        for e in cashflow_set.iterator():
            c = Cashflow(value=e.value, date=str(e.date));
            response_data[i] = c;

        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

here it is not possible to give model in json.dumps. But how i give more then 1 object to it?

error :

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, float found
[08/Sep/2016 14:14:00] "GET /getcashflow/ HTTP/1.1" 500 85775
```

Comment: There's django rest framework for this purpose, it has serializers (among a lot of other things) that allow to serialize collections. They also handle selection of fields to serialize to filter out sensitive data and different output formats.

Answer (score 19):

this is how to do it in general:

```
#view: 
from django.core import serializers

def get modelAPI(request):
    SomeModel_json = serializers.serialize("json", SomeModel.objects.all())
    data = {"SomeModel_json": SomeModel_json}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

for more you can see [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/serialization/)

Comment: serializers.serialize will only parse to string instead of true JSON

Comment: @davidvalentino try it after that: `struct = json.loads(SomeModel_json)`

Answer (score 3):

As @Ivan mentions the DRF does this out of the box if you want an API layer, but if you just want a basic view to return some json without the overhead of configuring a new package then it should be a fairly simple operation with django's serializers:

```
from django.core import serializers

def get_cashflows(request):

    response_data = {}
    cashflow_set = Cashflow.objects.all();
    i = 0;
    for e in cashflow_set.iterator():
        c = Cashflow(value=e.value, date=str(e.date));
        response_data[i] = c;

    return HttpResponse(
        serializers.serialize("json", response_data),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
```

The docs have a good break down of how to achieve this even if the default json serializer doesn't quite do what you need

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json

Also to note:

you could use the queryset directly `serializers.serialize("json", Cashflow.objects.all())`

and you're also not incrementing `i` in your loop...

Comment: Thx for the answer! Helps a lot! And oops, the incrementing i I must probably delete with some other code

Answer (score 0):

This is a project that it can serialize(JSON base now) all data in your model and put them to a specific directory automatically and then it can deserialize it whenever you want... I've personally serialized thousand records with this script and then load all of them back to another database without any losing data.

Anyone that would be interested in opensource projects can contribute this project and add more feature to it.

[serializer_deserializer_model](https://github.com/rainyman2012/model_serializer_deserializer/blob/master/serializer_deserializer.py)